# How can I perform arithmetics on bytes in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given any number of bytes (as a binary string), what is the best way to add or substract a number to/from the set of bytes and get back the new set of bytes?

Example (I'm looking for a good implementation of `add`):

```
>>> add('\xFF' * 10, 1)
'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

(Given 10 bytes with a value of 255, adding one would give you back 11 bytes where the first one has value 1 and the rest value 0)

Comment: "best" seems like a pretty relative term ...

Comment: Alright, changed it to "good".

Comment: Why do you need to perform the arithmetic this way? Binary is just another way to represent numbers. A number is a number. Do you really mean, "how can I represent some number as a series of 8-bit strings of bits"? And then, does that just mean, "how do I get a binary representation of a number"? Because all you did there is implement simple binary addition where the result happens to be 64-bits and doesn't roll over...

Comment: I want to be able to do arithmetics in base 256, yes. My example was actually with 32 bytes (256 bits), and I'm looking for an easy way to do that with any number of bytes, whether there's 5 bytes or 100.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest solution I can think of. I'm hoping there's a nicer way though:

```
def add(bytes, value):
  x = '%x' % (long(bytes.encode('hex'), 16) + value)
  return ('0' + x if len(x) & 1 else x).decode('hex')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python can do arbitrary length integer math

```
>>> a = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
>>> print hex( a+1 )
0x10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L
>>> b = (1 << 8*32) -1
>>> print hex(b)
0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffL
```

Comment: That's not working with bytes, that's just normal numbers. I'll clarify my question that I'm looking to work with an actual set of bytes (in Python 2.x, that's a binary string).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question